# concatenate expressions with brackets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've stumbled across some Python expression from which I don't know whether its tensorflow or Python related. Since Im not very profound in Python, I may ask if someone could explain me, what the concatenation of `(layer1)(layer2)` actually means:

```
d = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=f_size, strides=2, padding='same')(layer_input)
d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
```

d is later given as an `kwargs` argument in the `Model(*args, **kwargs)`.
Its not a simple multiplication `*` operation, Ive tried that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please add the code of "concatenate expression with brackets". Is it `model.add((layer1)(layer2))` ?

Comment: @Andrey its the code in the middle. Apparently you are right. It simply adds multiple layers. But how exactly does this operation work? Still confused.

Comment: I don't see code of concatenation in your question. Do you mean convolution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a concatenation. Those second brackets are inputs to the layer.

`Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=f_size, strides=2, padding='same')` returns function for which `(layer_input)` is input layer.

Comment: this makes sense, since the whole procedure should analog to adding the layers one by one. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question,

The concatenation of two layers in Keras intuitively means the merging of two layers. When you are using `Dense` layers, the concatenation will just append the second layer after the first. In convolution layers by default, concatenation works by appending channels of the second layer after the channels of the first layer.

ex) Conacatenation of `layer1(w,h,c1)` and `layer2(w,h,c2)` results `layer3(w,h,c1 + c2)`

[image: Visual example]